# How to point www.example.com/umbraco to admin.example.com

Tags: iis, umbraco, umbraco7

I have requirement to point www.example.com/umbraco to admin.example.com in iis.When user access to admin.example.com it should load umbraco backoffice. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out https://www.digbyswift.com/blog/2015/02/changing-umbracos-backoffice-address/.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main goal is to protect Umbraco admin area. You can do that with rewrite rules. I presume that your website in IIS already has two bindings: `www.example.com` and `admin.example.com`. Add this rules into your web.config:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="redirect to umbraco" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^admin.example.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="umbraco" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="close umbraco from public" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^umbraco(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^admin.example.com$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="redirect non umbraco to public" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^umbraco(.*)" negate="true" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^admin.example.com$" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

This rules will:

1) Redirect from `admin.example.com` to `admin.example.com/umbraco`

2) Close `/umbraco*` urls if you will try to access it from `www.example.com` domain.

3) Redirect all urls other than `/umbraco*` from domain `admin.example.com` to `www.example.com`